# How to free up memory "fully hibernating" a process?

Tags: windows, linux, process

Similar to this: [How to "hibernate a process" under Linux/Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/288390/how-to-hibernate-a-process-under-linux-windows)

Are there any methods to hibernate a process in a way that it doesn't stay in memory? E.g.: If I don't want to use Firefox, and don't want to close the process of it, and I need free memory, then how can I really hibernate the process so the memory reserved by Firefox is freed up?

I need solution for both Windows and Linux!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I don't want to use Firefox, and don't want to close the process of it, and I need free memory, then how can I really hibernate the process so the memory reserved by Firefox is freed up?

For Windows, there is [Free Process Freezer](http://download.cnet.com/Free-Process-Freezer/3000-2094_4-10976629.html).

For Linux and Mac OS X, there is [CrypoPID](http://cryopid.berlios.de/), as mentioned in [yeedl's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/288460/how-to-free-up-memory-fully-hibernating-a-process/288466#288466).

---

If you want to come up with a custom solution:

Look into `process dumping` on Windows, eg. [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900), resume it with a CLI debugger from [WinDBG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009).

Look into `core dumping` on Linux, eg. [core](http://linux.die.net/man/5/core), resume it with a CLI debugger like [GNU GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

I bet a software based solution that doesn't involve a debugger is possible, but that's for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

---

You're looking for a very specific use case, why don't just suspend and let it swap out?

You would be spending more time on getting your processes running and suspending...

I believe you can optimize your workflow in another way that would be more seamless.

Answer (score 5):

Both Windows and Linux/Unix provide a way to suspend or stop a process from executing, by removing it from the list of runnable processes.

This doesn't directly affect the memory pages owned by a process, but over time as the system comes under pressure for memory those pages will be good candidates to swap out to disk.

Trying to write out a process to disk for later resumption isn't going to work for anything non-trivial. Open handles to the network and windowing system will fail as soon as the process resumes.

Comment: It wouldn't work for anything trivial either. :) +1

Comment: Those open handles are just opened again or stored along, so that isn't really a problem...

Answer (score 2):

I know in [firefox](http://www.labnol.org/software/browsers/save-all-open-websites-firefox-tabs-sessions-quit/2382/) you can save a session.

In Linux, this can be done with [CrypoPID](http://cryopid.berlios.de/).

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/230818/windows-software-to-save-arbitrary-application-state) question and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/170434/save-and-restore-a-programs-state-in-windows) one try to answer it for Windows, but I couldn't find a great solution of saving an application state to a file like I did for linux.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:

I don't know any way to completely evict a process from memory without killing it, but you can trim its working set by minimizing its main window. Microsoft has an article explaining this: [The working set of an application is trimmed when its top-level window is minimized](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293215).

So, first minimize the main window(s), then suspend the process as suggested in the [question you linked](https://superuser.com/questions/288390/how-to-hibernate-a-process-under-linux-windows).

You can accomplish both with the ever-useful [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

- Right click process, Window -> Minimize
- Right click again, Suspend.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, some programs can swap-out "unused" program memory.
An example of a product that can do that is the commercial [Process Lasso](http://www.bitsum.com/prolasso.php).
However, even Process Lasso counsels against that practice.

From [The Truth about Windows Memory Optimizers](http://www.bitsum.com/winmemboost.htm) :

> It is best to leave the management of
>   virtual memory to Windows and not take
>   it into your own hands. Any benefit
>   from these programs is an illusion and
>   temporary. You incur the penalties of
>   paging memory back in sooner or later,
>   even if it appears that the program
>   you run after the cleanup loads
>   faster.

Now as regarding Firefox, see mozillaZine's [Reducing memory usage - Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Memory_Leak), which contains lots of advice on how to discover which extensions leak memory.

There is also the Firefox extension [Memory Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/memory-fox/) which :

> Attempting to reduce the browser's RAM
>   Memory usage promoting the increase of
>   available RAM memories for other
>   application processes RAM memory
>   requirements. Hopefully, fostering any
>   attempts of Memory Recovery and
>   Retention.

In my experience this extension only postpones the inevitable memory-bloat of Firefox. The only real solution is to close Firefox from time to time to liberate memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can send STOP signal to processes in Linux. A stopped process is like *paused*. To resume it send the process CONT signal. To send the signal you can do this:

```
kill -STOP process_id

kill -CONT process_id
```

A stopped process will be swapped out if system requires more memory.